# Regex Get Everything Between 2 Words

Tags: regex, uipath

I need to find in text the last match word "Madhuparna" and get text between the left near match tag html to last tag html in text.

- Word to find:

`Madhuparna`

- Text input:

`<p>The entire purpose speed up the process.</p><p>June 5, 2021 By Demo</p>\r\n<p>The entire purpose of a terminal emulator is to imitate how the regular computer terminals perform</p><p>Allowing the main computer to connect Madhuparna to and use a remote computer</p><li>bla bla bla bla bla bla</li>`

- Result that I need:

`<p>Allowing the main computer to connect Madhuparna to and use a remote computer</p><li>bla bla bla bla bla bla</li>`

- What I have to now but not work:

`/<(\S+)(>| .*?>)[^<>]*Madhuparna[^<>]*<\/\1>/g`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```cs
(?s)<\w+(?:\s[^>]*)?>[^<>]*Madhuparna.*</\w+>
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3c%5cw%2b%28%3f%3a%5cs%5b%5e%3e%5d*%29%3f%3e%5b%5e%3c%3e%5d*Madhuparna.*%3c%2f%5cw%2b%3e&i=%3cp%3eThe+entire+purpose+speed+up+the+process.%3c%2fp%3e%3cp%3eJune+5%2c+2021+By+Demo%3c%2fp%3e%5cr%5cn%3cp%3eThe+entire+purpose+of+a+terminal+emulator+is+to+imitate+how+the+regular+computer+terminals+perform%3c%2fp%3e%3cp%3eAllowing+the+main+computer+to+connect+Madhuparna+to+and+use+a+remote+computer%3c%2fp%3e%3cli%3ebla+bla+bla+bla+bla+bla%3c%2fli%3e&o=s). *Details*:

- `(?s)` - an inline `singleline` flag
- `<` - `<` char
- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `(?:\s[^>]*)?` - an optional occurrence of a whitespace and then zero or more chars other than `>`
- `>` - a `>` char
- `[^<>]*` - zero or more chars other than `<` and `>`
- `Madhuparna` - a substring
- `.*` - any zero or more chars, as many as possible
- `</\w+>` - a `</` string, any one or more word chars, `>`.